# Microsoft Word 2016 does not recognize computer generated headings

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting

I am using Word 2016. I am trying to merge two documents with different heading orders. One of them is generated via Matlab and its heading system is like the following,

1.1.1.1something_main (without space between numbers and letters)

Each heading has its own figure captions like the following
Figure 1.3. something_main_CDF

When I copy and paste this stuff to the other, word does not recognize that these are headers even if I add space between the letters and the numbers. Thus, I need to delete all the numbers, make it heading and do the same for the figure manually. I would appreciate any help to do it automatically since it takes so long to do it.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, what you want is to preserve some kind of formatting. This can be done, follow the answer from @gargamel: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387453/how-do-you-display-code-snippets-in-ms-word-preserving-format-and-syntax-highlig

Comment: Actually what I want is the opposite. I want Word to recognize the text that I am pasting as heading and rearrange the numbers automatically. Sorry if my English is not clear enough.

Comment: I assume you are looking for an automated function that turns normal lines into headings. Unfortunately, this is not possible unless you find a macro that is well programmed to suit your needs.